# how to show data from hibernate to the textarea of JavaFX and iterate it using Button

Tags: database, hibernate, javafx-8

i cant fetch the quizes from the Quiz table and show it in the textarea one by one by pressing the next button.. kindly help me to find out solution

```
public class QuizesController implements Initializable {
    int id=1;

    @FXML
    private Label l1;
    @FXML
    private Label l2;
    @FXML
    private Label l3;
    @FXML
    private Label l4;
    @FXML
    private TextArea txtQuiz;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton c1;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton c2;
    @FXML
    private RadioButton c3;
    @FXML
    private Button btnNext;
    @FXML
    private Button btnStart;


    /**
     *
     * @param event
     * @throws IOException
     */
    @FXML
    public void setBtnNextclicked(javafx.event.ActionEvent event) throws IOException{

        SessionFactory sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
        Session sessin=sessionfactory.openSession();
        sessin.beginTransaction();
        id++;
    //    String query="select question,choicea,choiceb,choicec from student where id=:id";
    //    Query hql=sessin.createQuery(query).setParameter("id",id);
        Quiz q=(Quiz) sessin.get(Quiz.class,id);
        txtQuiz.setText(q.question);
        c1.setText(q.getChoicea());
        c2.setText(q.getChoiceb());
        c3.setText(q.getChoicec());

        sessin.close();


    }
```

Comment: So what actually happens? Do you get any exceptions? If so, post the stack trace.

Comment: i cant develop logic for this scenario, kindly help me

Comment: the user will be shown the quizzes one-by-one on the next button click

Comment: I meant, what happens when you run the code you posted?

Comment: code is running but no output :(

Comment: code is running without error

Comment: no desired outcome.. next value from Quiz table that is id: 2 is not fetched and not showing on textarea